# How to find space in a japanese string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, utf, autocorrect

I am working on an auto correct program for Japanese sentences and the missing character in the sentence would be represented as a space.

I am reading from 2 files...

Input file:

```
　はアビガイル
おはよう　くん
```

Dictionary file:

```
私はアビガイル
おはよう花くん
```

The missing characters 私 and 花 are represented as a space

How can I find the space from the input file?

I tried `lineFromFile.find(" ")` but it returns trash since it is not the usual english characters. Also tried `lineFromFile.find('\0x20')` and `lineFromFile.find(' ')`

I also tried `string lineFromFile = u8"あび"` but u8 prefix gets an error "identifier 'u8' is undefined"

I am using **C++**, Visual Studio 2013, gcc 4.8.3 and my current code page is Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)

**If you think this is a duplicate question, please comment the link to the same ANSWERED question**

My plan is:

1. Find the space from the line of the input file (return the `spaceIndex`)
2. Save the line from the dictionary file in `string temp`
3. Replace the character in `spaceIndex` in the variable `temp` will be
4. Compare the line from the input file to `temp`
5. Repeat until match is found or until eof of dictionary file

**Please help, I have 3 days :'(**

Comment: What do you mean by "returns trash"? A space in UTF-8 is a single 1-byte character, you should be able to find it OK. What does `lineFromFile.find(' ')` return? Also I don't know about Visual Studio but `u8"あび"` should work fine with GCC 4.8

Comment: Your plan won't work, because although a space takes up a single `char` in the string, the character at the same position in the dictionary file will be a multi-byte character, so substituting just a single byte from the dictionary string to the input string won't work. You should convert the strings to `u32string` before processing them, so that each character takes a single `char32_t` and you can substitute single characters at the same offset in the strings. In Visual Studio you can use `wstring_convert` and `codecvt<char32_t>` for the conversion, but GCC 4.8 doesn't support those types.

Comment: @JonathanWakely when I printed the return of find it printed `4294967295` .  `lineFromFile.find(' ')` returned the same thing. I googled that u8 should have worked but it just doesn't, should I #include something other than `<iostream>`, `<fstream>`,  `<string>`, `<vector>` ?

Comment: @R.A. `4294967295` is 32-bit `-1` reinterpreted as an an unsigned 32-bit integer. `-1` is what `find` returns when it fails.

Comment: i.e. 4294967295 is `std::string::npos`, which is what `find` is documented to return, so it's not trash at all.

Comment: Are you sure the input files are UTF-8 encoded? Maybe you're reading UTF-16 files and trying to interpret them as UTF-8, which would explain why you can't find a `' '` character

Comment: @JonathanWakely there is an advance save option in visual studio that sets that it is utf-8 but as for the files, I am not sure cause I don't know how know if the file is UTF-16 or 8. It is save as .txt

Comment: Maybe you should find out. I'd use the `file` command to tell me, but then I use a real operating system not a toy. There must be some way to get something on Windows to tell you a file's encoding.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I tried `file` and it says that the files I'm reading are "UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators"

Comment: OK, that's good. But then it doesn't make sense that `find(' ')` returns `npos`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I really don't know what to do now, is it the headers or my version of gcc ? I'm really stuck.

Comment: OK, the problem seems to be that you lied to us :-) The blank character in your input string is not a space, it is http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x3000/index.html, but the good news is that maybe all the Japanese characters you need to work with are stored as 3 bytes in UTF-8, so you can search for `u8"\u3000"` to find the ideographic space characters, then replace three bytes at a time. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/515974758e685f84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The missing characters 私 and 花 are represented as a space

No they aren't. Looking at 　`はアビガイル` in a hex editor shows that the first character is `'\u3000'` which is [IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) not [SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm).

So to find it you need to use `find(u8"\u3000")` or `find("\xe3\x80\x80)`

If you're lucky and all the Japanese characters in your input files are encoded as three bytes in UTF-8 then you can treat them as having fixed positions in the strings and substitute blocks of three bytes from one string to another.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Found the space using `find("\xe3\x80\x80")`. I also think you're right about it being stored as 3 bytes cause I tried it with `こにちわ　くん` and it returned 12. This is my first time encountering ideographic space. I thought a space is just a space, I really need to study more of unicode characters :)) Thank you again!!! :D